# Expected number of unique items when drawing with replacement

Tags: probability

Having a set of size M, I'm drawing M items with replacement. What is expected number of unique items that got picked?

Thanks,
Jarek

Comment: Tell us if you have tried something.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Let $Y$ be the number of unique items that get picked.  Let $X_i$ be $1$ if item $i$ gets picked and $0$ if not.  We have $E[X_i] = 1 P(X_i = 1) + 0 P(X_i = 0) = P(X_i = 1) = 1 - P(X_i = 0)$.  Since $P(X_i = 0)$ is the probability that item $i$ is *not* picked, this is the probability that $i$ is not picked with any of the first, second, third, etc., choices.  Thus $P(X_i = 0) = \left(\frac{M-1}{M}\right)^M$.

Therefore, $$\begin{align}E[Y] &= E\left[\sum_{i=1}^M X_i\right] = \sum_{i=1}^M E[X_i] = \sum_{i=1}^M P(X_i = 1) = \sum_{i=1}^M \left(1 - \left(\frac{M-1}{M}\right)^M\right) \\
&= M - \frac{(M-1)^M}{M^{M-1}}.\end{align}$$

In general, using indicator functions to calculated expected values can be very helpful.  For more examples, see the answers to [Find the expectation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19219/find-the-expectation/19225#19225) or [Another balls and bins question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28930/another-balls-and-bins-question/28932#28932) or [Expected number of neighbors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9522/expected-number-of-neighbors/9535#9535).

Comment: I don't understand why the expected number of unique elements in the sample is equal to the sum of the probabilities that item $i$ gets picked or sum of the expectations of item $i$ being picked.

Answer (score 15):

Thanks for great answer Mike!

I just would like to add that if someone is interested in percent of picked items, then
$$
\frac{M - \frac{(M-1)^M}{M^{M-1}}}{M} = \frac{M - M\left(\frac{M-1}{M} \right)^M}{M} = 1 - \left(1 - \frac{1}{M} \right )^M
$$

For large M it is approximately 
$$
1 - \frac{1}{e} \simeq 0.632120559 \dots
$$

because

$$
\lim_{M\to\infty}\left(1 - \frac{1}{M} \right )^M = \frac{1}{e}
$$